# Start / stop a script with buttons

Tags: gpio

i want to start and stop this script with a buttons 1 button to start and one to stop using gpio pins 35 and 37

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from random import randint
import SimpleMFRC522
import time
import subprocess
import os
import logging
import random
import glob
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO


def playmovie(video, aspect = 0):

    """plays a video."""

    global myprocess
    global directory

    logging.debug('linux: omxplayer %s' % video)

    proccount = isplaying()

    if proccount == 1 or proccount == 0:

        logging.debug('No videos playing, so play video')

    else:

        logging.debug('Video already playing, so quit current video, then play')
        myprocess.communicate(b"q")

    if aspect == 0:
        myprocess = subprocess.Popen(['omxplayer',directory + video],stdin=subprocess.PIPE,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE, close_fds=True)

    else:
    #This is for videos that come in 16:9 that should be played as 4:3
    #if your video file is already in 4:3, you don't need to set this flag.
        myprocess = subprocess.Popen(['omxplayer','--win','250,0,1650,1050',directory + video],stdin=subprocess.PIPE,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE, close_fds=True)

    time.sleep(3)

def isplaying():

        """check if omxplayer is running
        if the value returned is a 1 or 0, omxplayer is NOT playing a video
        if the value returned is a 2, omxplayer is playing a video"""

        processname = 'omxplayer'
        tmp = os.popen("ps -Af").read()
        proccount = tmp.count(processname)

        return proccount

#program start

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

reader = SimpleMFRC522.SimpleMFRC522()

directory = '/media/pi/BILLYUSB1/'

print("Begin Player")

try:
    while True: 

        proccount = isplaying()

        if proccount == 1 or proccount == 0:

            current_movie_id = long(10)

        start_time = time.time()

        logging.debug("Waiting for ID to be scanned")
        id, movie_name = reader.read()

        logging.debug("ID: %s" % id)
        logging.debug("Movie Name: %s" % movie_name)

        movie_name = movie_name.rstrip()

        if current_movie_id != id:

            logging.debug('New Movie')
            #this is a check in place to prevent omxplayer from restarting video if ID is left over the reader.
            #better to use id than movie_name as there can be a problem reading movie_name occasionally


            if movie_name.endswith(('.mp4', '.avi', '.m4v','.mkv')):
                current_movie_id = id   #we set this here instead of above bc it may mess up on first read
                logging.debug("playing: omxplayer %s" % movie_name)
                playmovie(movie_name)

            elif 'folder' in movie_name:
            #randomly plays video files from a certain folder
                current_movie_id = id
                movie_directory = movie_name.replace('folder',"") 
                movie_name = random.choice(glob.glob(os.path.join(directory + movie_directory, '*')))
                movie_name = movie_name.replace(directory,"")

                logging.debug("randomly playing: omxplayer %s" % movie_name)
                playmovie(movie_name)


            elif 'fourthree' in movie_name:
            #video files randomly played from a folder and that should be played in 4:3 aspect ratio
                current_movie_id = id
                movie_directory = movie_name.replace('fourthree',"")
                movie_name = random.choice(glob.glob(os.path.join(directory + movie_directory, '*')))
                movie_name = movie_name.replace(directory,"")

                logging.debug("randomly playing: omxplayer %s" % movie_name)
                playmovie(movie_name,1)

        else:

            end_time = time.time()
            elapsed_time = end_time - start_time
            proccount = isplaying()

            if proccount != 1 and proccount != 0:

                if elapsed_time > 0.6:
                    #pause, unpause movie

                    logging.debug('Pausing movie - or - Playing movie')
                    myprocess.stdin.write("p")


except KeyboardInterrupt:
    GPIO.cleanup()
    print("\nAll Done")
```

Comment: I see no code that attempts to read buttons. What have you tried?

Comment: It should Be on there dirk

Answer (score 0):

You just want to trigger these on button push? Save them as a program, write a secont program that imports them, and states 'if pin X=1(or True)(*pin number X is end pin for button. Hook Vin to 3.3v out on Pi) and then tell it the name of the function your running. Or program a GUI and put the programs as functions, and call the function on pinX=True. If you need help with Tkinter im pretty good at it having just programmed an R2D2 for remote access, control, and video output using a Rpi zeroW

Comment: yah i am now to all of this i have no idea how to do any of that

Comment: from time import sleep
import os
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
button1=35
GPIO.setup(button1,GPIO.IN,pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
while(1):
        if GPIO.input(button1)==0:
                os.system("python /home/pi/MFRC522-python/bplay.py")
                print "Button 1 Pressed"
                sleep(.1)

Comment: that is the code i made it works but once clicked never stops

Comment: You have to add an end point or it wont. What you have is an infinite while loop. You need if else. If button=1 do blah, else stop. Plus ove noticed with rpi: use BCM numbering. I started with board numbering and alot of python libraries dont like it. Like PWM doesnt work right 100% of the time unless you use BCM.

Comment: Charles beason Can you add it to my code so I get it right

Comment: I am currently traveling for work and away from my lab, however i will work up a demo script for you this weekend

Comment: For starters change numbering to 19 and 26.

Comment: from time import sleep import os import RPi.GPIO as GPIO GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM) button1=19 button2=26 GPIO.setup(button1,GPIO.IN) GPIO.setup(button2, GPIO.IN) if button1=True:*run script* print 'button1 pressed' else if button2=True:*stop script* print'button2pressed'

Comment: thanks i will give it a try and let you know